# Problemas creando BD android

Tags: android

Estoy siguiendo el tutorial de Android Developers para crear una BD:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=es#WriteDbRow

Uso Android Studio 2.2.3 y un Alcatel Pixi 4 con Android 6.0 para las pruebas.
Al ejecutar la App que tan sólo debe crear una BD con una tabla e insertar un registro, en el dispositivo aparece la pantalla de la App con el típico Hola mundo. El problema es que no me aparece el fichero con la BD en el ADM / DDMS
En el File explorer el directorio "data/" sólo contiene un fichero "default.pro"

Estas son las clases con el código:

```
// MainActivity.java
package com.example.orici.dbtest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper( this );
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, "Mi título");
        values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, "Unas pruebas");

        long newRowId = db.insert(
            FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values
        );
    }

} //class



// FeedReaderContract.java
package com.example.orici.dbtest;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class FeedReaderContract {

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    protected static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
    protected static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    private FeedReaderContract() {}

    // Inner class that defines the table contents
    public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME           = "entry";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE    = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";

    } //class
} //class



//FeedReaderDbHelper.java
package com.example.orici.dbtest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import static com.example.orici.dbtest.FeedReaderContract.SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES;

public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( FeedReaderContract.SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES );
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( FeedReaderContract.SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES );
        onCreate(db);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

} //class
```

Comment: Podrías decir toda la ruta en la que buscas? /data...

Comment: El directorio "data/" me aparece directamente al abrir el File explorer, el problema es que no tiene más contenido que el fichero que he indicado. He probado a ejecutar el proyecto con un emulador, aunque nunca me han funcionado..., entonces si aparece "data/data/" y el signo más como que hay contenid Añadir comentario

ayuda
o, pero no permite desplegarlo.

Answer (score 0):

> El problema es que no me aparece el fichero con la BD en el ADM / DDMS
>   En el File explorer el directorio "data/" sólo contiene un fichero
>   "default.pro"

Anteriormente cuando se usaba el plugin de Android en Eclipse (cuando no existía Android Studio), se podía ver la base de datos mediante el `File Explorer` aún y cuando la base de datos fuera creada en el directorio interno del dispositivo.

Actualmente por motivos de permisos, no se puede acceder a visualizar datos de almacenamiento interno a menos que tengas tu dispositivo Android como `ROOT`.

Una opción para obtener la base de datos es realizar una copia de la base de datos del almacenamiento interno al externo:

[¿Como copiar una base de datos o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno-al-exte)

---

Para obtener la ruta de la base de datos puedes usar el método [getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)), indicando el nombre de la base de datos :

```
String dbname = "FeedReader.db";
Path dbpath = ctx.getDatabasePath(dbname);
```