# ¿Como copiar una base de datos Sqlite o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Como copiar un archivo o base de datos desde el almacenamiento interno al externo, en ocasiones requerimos leer archivos  dentro del almacenamiento interno ( `data/data` ), lo cual es únicamente posible si el dispositivo tiene permisos de root.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de un dispositivo que no tiene estos permisos, es imposible acceder a la información.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### ¿Cómo exportar e importar una base de datos SQLite de Android?

Sugiero este método

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        File dir = new File(to.substring(0, to.lastIndexOf('/')));
        dir.mkdirs();
        File tof = new File(dir, to.substring(to.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        int byteread;
        File oldfile = new File(from);
        if(oldfile.exists()){
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(tof);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();
        }
        result = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("copyFile", "Error copiando archivo: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

el cual sería llamado de esta forma, conociendo el paquete de tu aplicación y el nombre del archivo o base de datos guardada, indicas fuente y destino de archivo a copiar:

```
//Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
String pathDB = getDatabasePath(NOMBRE_DATABASE).toString();
//Copia base de datos a destino definido.
copyFile(pathDB, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/" + <nombre archivo destino>);
```

No olvidar agregar el permiso para poder escribir en el almacenamiento externo:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Con este método puedes copiar tanto ficheros como una base de datos a el almacenamiento externo para de esta forma poder sin problema abrir los archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### *Importante:

para usar el permiso **[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** en dispositivos con sistema operativo mayor a **[Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** (que implícitamente es también `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ) se debe requerir manualmente:

```
//Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Usa este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934)