# No puedo guardar o encontrar archivo en el almacenamiento local (local storage) de mi aplicación Android

Tags: android

He seguido [las instrucciones de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html) para guardar un archivo en el local storage de mi App.

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
      Log.i(TAG, "writeToFile OK" );

   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Luego yo intento ver si mi archivo se encuentra dentro de algún folder con la app `Explorador`, pero no lo encuentro por ningún lado.

En el Log se puede ver que efectivamente el código entra en el `try` ya que imprime `writeToFile OK` y no hay errores.

**¿Por qué no encuentro el archivo?**

**NOTA:**
Probé con y sin los permisos que indica Android:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

En la documentación tampoco queda claro si ese permiso es sólo para escribir en el almacenamiento externo. Por el nombre parece que sí. De todos modos probé con ese permiso y sin él, y no encuentro el archivo de ninguna manera.

Comment: Donde lo instalaste verifica primero que la app tenga permisos de escritura y lectura, ya que algunas veces este permiso no se otorga y lo tienes que agregar manualmente, entra a configuracion y aplicaciones y busca tu app y solo verifica si en permisos tiene activada la parte de escritura, lectura.

Comment: Imagino tienes permisos Root por eso puedes buscar en el almacenamiento interno?

Comment: @jorgesys yo estoy buscando en una app llamada `Explorador` que viene con el teléfono. Pero no veo el archivo. He hecho una prueba de lectura y funciona. El archivo está almacenado efectivamente. Creía que podía verlo en el explorador pero no lo encuentro. El explorador me muestra carpetas de otras apps, pero no de la mía.

Comment: se cual es la app que comentas, pero si no tienes permisos Root no puedes acceder a ver la estructura del almacenamiento interno, (hace años con Eclipse se podía mediante el File Explorer :( ) , de hecho la ruta del almacenamiento interno es generalmente: /data/user/0/<paquete>/files/<nombre archivo> pero no es accesible si no tienes permisos Root. @A.Cedano

Comment: Me vino a la mente este caso : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno-al-exte Se desea ver la base de datos de una aplicación, pero si no se tienen permisos Root no se puede visualizar, una opción es realizar una copia desde el almacenamiento interno al externo, en el externo se puede ver sin problemas @A.Cedano

Comment: @jorgesys es como si no dejara leer el archivo desde fuera de su propia app. He leído que se podría por ADB, yo solo quería comprobar mediante la aplicación `Explorador` que el archivo estaba ahí. Pero parece que no se puede. Aunque Android no habla de esa restricción. Lo extraño es que puedo ver carpetas de otras apps en el explorador y ver sus archivos, pero de la mía no veo nada.

Comment: Entiendo lo que comentas, puedes ver por ejemplo lo que se encuentra dentro de emulated/0/Android/data/ y aquí  dentro aplicaciones con archivos, pero si tienen archivos que se crearon o descargaron al almacenamiento externo se pueden visualizar aquí, pero si se crearon en almacenamiento interno existen pero no se pueden visualizar si no se tienen permisos Root.

Comment: Para almacenamiento interno no aplica, no es necesario agregar el permiso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` aplica para escribir en el almacenamiento externo, es inherente la lectura, por lo tanto no se necesita `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

**[Para el almacenamiento interno NO es necesario el permiso](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).**

> Puedes guardar archivos directamente en el almacenamiento interno del
>   dispositivo. De forma predeterminada, los archivos que se guardan en
>   el almacenamiento interno son privados para tu aplicación y otras
>   aplicaciones no pueden tener acceso a ellos (tampoco el usuario).
>   Cuando el usuario desinstala tu aplicación, estos archivos se quitan.

el código que muestras en realidad es para crear un archivo en el almacenamiento interno:

```
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
      Log.i(TAG, "writeToFile OK" );
```

Alternativamente puedes usar `getFilesDir()` para guardar el archivo en el almacenamiento interno.

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
```

---

Para probar si tu archivo fue creado en verdad con cualquiera de las opciones anteriores en el almacenamiento interno puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
    if(file.exists()){
        Log.i(TAG, "EXISTE!");
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "NO EXISTE!");
    }
```

**Para visualizar la estructura del almacenamiento interno es necesario tener permisos Root.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]