# Como incluir un fichero txt, ya creado, en tu proyecto Android

Tags: android, archivo

He estado revisando como trabajar con ficheros en Android y he realizado algunas prácticas sobre como crear un fichero, escribir sobre éste, leer, etc.

Pero, ¿y si el fichero yo ya lo tengo creado?, imaginad que quiero insertar en mi aplicación un fichero con un listado de preguntas y respuestas, por ejemplo.

Redacto el fichero en el formato que me interesa pero después, ¿qué hago?, ¿cómo lo agrego al proyecto Android?

Comment: José, revisa si [lo planteado aquí te puede servir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/136709/29967). En la pregunta también hay un enlace a la documentación de Android.

Comment: Como bien dice @DamianGonzalezFernandez en su respuesta, metes el archivo en la carpeta raw y ya puedes acceder a el sin problemas

Comment: Si la carpeta no existe, ¿la creo manualmente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mételo en una carpeta llamada "raw" dentro de la carpeta "res" (donde están los drawables, layouts, etc.

```
InputStream raw = context.getAssets().open("tufichero.txt");
Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF8"));
```

Comment: Si la carpeta no existe, ¿la creo manualmente?

Comment: Puedes añadirla manualmente desde el explorador de archivos de tu sistema operativo o desde Android Studio, que también te da opción de hacerlo apretando sobre res con el botón derecho del ratón.