# como hacer una copia de archivo sqlite a la memoria externa

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

estoy intentando crear una copia a la memoria sd, pero el procedimiento que hago no me hace nada ni me sale error, tengo los permisos de escritura este es el codigo que estoy implementando

```
 public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
        boolean result = false;
        try{
            File dir = new File(to.substring(0, to.lastIndexOf('/')));
            dir.mkdirs();
            File tof = new File(dir, to.substring(to.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
            int byteread;
            File oldfile = new File(from);

            if(oldfile.exists()){
               // System.exit(0);
                InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
                FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(tof);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
                }
                inStream.close();
                fs.close();

            }
            result = true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("copyFile", "Error copiando archivo: " + e.getMessage());

        }
        return result;
    }
```

de aqui llamo al procedimiento

```
 String nombd = "DBUsuarios";

               //Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
            String pathDB = getDatabasePath(nombd).toString();
              //Copia base de datos a destino definido.
            copyFile(pathDB,""+Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
```

Permisos

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: ¿Que error se muestra en el LogCat? , revisa lo que agrego como respuesa

Answer (score 0):

Puede que la validacion que estes haciendo este mal por eso no se ejecuta el codigo y no da error.
Fijate que estas haciendo:

```
if(oldfile.exists()){...}
```

cuando se supone que oldfile tiene que existir para luego copiarlo, bastaria hacer:

```
if(!oldfile.exists()){...}
```

Ojala sea eso solo, suerte

Comment: El problema seguramente son los permisos, el ejemplo lo tomo de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno-al-exte/79011#79011

Answer (score 0):

Hola Juan veo que el código lo obtuviste de este ejemplo:

**[¿Como copiar una base de datos Sqlite o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno-al-exte/79011#79011)**

he modificado mi respuesta en esa pregunta ya que para usar el permiso **[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** en dispositivos con sistema operativo mayor a **[Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** este debe ser requerido manualmente:

```
//Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Usa este método para requerir el permiso:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Comment: HOLA ME SALE EN ROJO ESTA PARTE ''WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: Si se muestra en rojo es que lo escribiste incorrectamente es Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: lo copie tal y como lo tienes en el ejemplo tambien revice el manifest y esta bien escrito

Comment: Manifest.permission. al escribir el punto solo muestra la opcion class

Comment: @juanperez asegura que tengas el import: "import android.Manifest;" si tienes otro eliminalo.

Comment: ok ya no me sale en rojo voy a ejecutar el procedimiento aunque no se si funcione en emulador

Comment: No he podido no me copia el archivo

Comment: Es importante revises el LogCat si te muestra algún error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84092/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-juan-perez).