# Como puedo crear base de datos en el almacenamiento externo SD

Tags: android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Me gustaría crear la base de datos directamente en el directorio de sistema de archivos donde se guardan los archivos internos de mi aplicación y acceder a estos con `getFilesDir()`.

Me encuentro con el problema que cuando se crea la base de datos dentro del proyecto y hago un backup luego no lo puedo restaurar porque no tengo acceso root.

¿Seria posible hacer esto?. ¿Como seria el código para indicar al creador de la base de datos sqlite que cree esta en la ruta que yo quiero?.

Espero haberme explicado con claridad y espero que me podais ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa esta publicacion, la crea en la memoria interna pero la pasas a la SD y es casi lo mismo. > https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas acceso root para restaurar? Puedes hacerlo dentro de tu aplicación, que tiene todos los accesos necesarios para hacerlo en dentro de sus carpetas. Solo asegúrate que no tienes ninguna conexión abierta para que los archivos no estén en uso y los sustituyes directamente.

Comment: ¿Pero como podría hacer que mi base de datos se crease directamente en /data/com.miproyecto/Files/Micarpeta/miBD.sqlite?, No quiero que la creer en /data/data/com.miproyecto/Databases/miBD.sqlite