# Problemas con Android Leer data/data/com.****/database

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un gran problemas, y es poder leer el archivo /data/data/com.***/databases/***.db, el celular lo tengo con ROOT, busque en todo los foros y tengo agregado

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
```

Pensando que si ya tiene el permiso de administrador deberia ller todo los datos, pero no al momento de copiar me dice "Permiso denegado"

```java
try {
      File sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
      File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

      if (sd.canWrite()) {
          String currentDBPath = "/data/data/com.***/databases/***.db";

          String backupDBPath = "data.db";

          File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
          File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

          if (currentDB.exists()) {
               FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
               FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
               dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
               src.close();
               dst.close();
          }
      }
} catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Tambien probe con comando adb:

```java
try {

            /*String fine = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/msgstore.db";

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","run-as com.whatsapp cat /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db"
            }).waitFor();

            Toast.makeText(application,"Finalizo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c",
                    "mount -o rw,remount /system",
                    "chmod 777 /data/data/com.*****/databases/*.*" ,
                    "cp /data/data/com.*****/databases/***.db /sdcard/respaldo.db",

                    "mount -o ro,remount /system"
            }).waitFor();

            File currentDB = new File("/sdcard/respaldo.db");
            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(application,"El archivo existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(application,"El archivo no existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Toast.makeText(application,"Error : "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Y el error fue que las direcciones no existen, si existen las comprobé, alguien ayúdeme por favor

Answer (score 0):

NO olvidar agregar el permiso para poder LEER/escribir en el almacenamiento externo:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Si el sistema operativo es Android 6.0 o posterior, tienes que requerir permisos manualmente.

[Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-un-alertdialog-en-android/24934#24934)

---

El permiso `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />` me parece que es obsoleto desde android 5.0

Si deseas leer tu base de datos desde el dispositivo, lo puedes realizar desde la misma aplicación, en este caso define el nombre de la base de datos y obtendrás la ruta:

```
String pathDB = getDatabasePath(NOMBRE_DATABASE).toString();
```

En este caso no necesitas un dispositivo "Rooted", lo que necesitas es copiar la base de datos ubicada en el almacenamiento interno a un directorio en el externo, el procedimiento se explica aquí:

[¿Como copiar una base de datos Sqlite o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno/79011#79011)