# Como hacer una copia de una base de datos sqlite y compartirla

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, android-sqlite, sqlite3

Necesito crear una app que haga una backup de la base de datos que usa para poder ser abierta por la misma app instalada en el mismo dispositivo o en otra. Pero no tengo idea sobre como puedo lograr tal cosa. (espero explicarme bien)

La base de datos se crea de la siguiente manera:

```
public class baseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public baseDeDatos(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario("+
                    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                    "nombre VARCHAR(25),"+
                    "pass VARCHAR(25),"+
                    "nick VARCHAR(25)"+
                    ");");
}
```

y se rellena con:

```
public void Registrar_on_click(View view)
{
    baseDeDatos admin = new baseDeDatos(this,"BaseDatos.sqlite", null, 3);
    SQLiteDatabase base = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    String nombre = etNombre.getText().toString();
    String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
    String nick = etNick.getText().toString();

    if (!nombre.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty() && !nick.isEmpty() )
    {
        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("nombre",nombre);
        registro.put("pass",pass);
        registro.put("nick",nick);

        base.insert("usuario", null, registro);
        base.close();

        etNombre.setText("");
        etPass.setText("");
        etNick.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro exitoso\n" +
                "Nombre: "+nombre+"\nPass: "+pass+"\nNick: "+nick,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Llenar los campos de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al crear tu base de datos esta se crea en un directorio de almacenamiento interno, si deseas que pueda ser visible para otras debes crear una copia, ya que de otra forma únicamente sería visible para tu aplicación.

Para esto te sugiero usar el método :

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        File dir = new File(to.substring(0, to.lastIndexOf('/')));
        dir.mkdirs();
        File tof = new File(dir, to.substring(to.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        int byteread;
        File oldfile = new File(from);
        if(oldfile.exists()){
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(tof);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();
        }
        result = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("copyFile", "Error copiando archivo: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

lo debes llamar de esta forma para crear la copia:

```
//Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
String pathDB = getDatabasePath("BaseDatos.sqlite").toString();

copyFile(pathDB, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/" + "BaseDatos.sqlite");
```

Puedes ver el procedimiento completo en esta respuesta:

[¿Como copiar una base de datos Sqlite o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno)