# App propia no funciona en Xiaomi Redmi note 9

Tags: android

Hola tengo una app que funciona bien en un Xiaomi Redmi 7 y Xiaomi Mi A1.
Pero al instalarla en un nuevo telefono que he adquirido un Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 hay una parte que ha dejado de funcioanar.

Cuando intento crear una copia de seguridad, lo realizo creando una carpeta llamada "laquesea" con un subdirectoria "Copia" y ahi dentro grabo la base de dato *.db. Pero con este nuevo telefono ni se crea la carpeta y ademas tambien no crea los pdf de otra parte de la app.

Me he dado cuenta que al crear la copia de seguridad en el codigo al llegar al if (pathdestino.canWrite()) { no lo hace, no entra por lo cual no crea nada

¿Por que puede ser?

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void copiaDatabase(){
    try {
        String DBName = "tesoreria.db";
        File pathdestino = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File pathorigen = getActivity().getDatabasePath(DBName);
        if (pathdestino.canWrite()) {

            String destinoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File directorio = new File(destinoPath + File.separator + CARPETA);
            if (!directorio.exists()) { directorio.mkdir(); }

            File subdirectorio = new File(directorio + File.separator + SUBCARPETA);
            if (!subdirectorio.exists()) { subdirectorio.mkdir(); }

            String origenDBPath = pathorigen.toString();
            String destinoDBPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + CARPETA + File.separator + SUBCARPETA + File.separator + DBName;
            File destinofichero = new File( destinoDBPath );
            if (!destinofichero.exists()) { destinofichero.delete(); }

            File origenDB = new File(origenDBPath);
            File destinoDB = new File(destinoDBPath);

            FileChannel origen = new FileInputStream(origenDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel destino = new FileOutputStream(destinoDB).getChannel();
            destino.transferFrom(origen, 0, origen.size());
            origen.close();
            destino.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar la Copia de Seguridad. Intentelo más tarde.")
                .setTitle("ERROR Copia de Seguridad")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apoyo24)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
        alertDialogCopiaError.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suena a un problema de permisos en tu dispositivo nuevo o a que la carpeta no se crea correctamente.

Comment: Los permisos los tiene. Permiso de acceso a Almacenamiento interno

Comment: ¿El Log cat no muestra ningún error?

Comment: NO. Simplemente no entra en el   if (pathdestino.canWrite()) {...}   Lo curioso es que en  el Mi A1 con API 29 si funciona perfectamente, y en este Redmi Note 9 No.  La aplicacion esta desarrollada para API 26

Comment: ¿En el Manifest tienes todos los permisos necesarios, incluyendo `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: SI. Esto es lo que tengo: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: ¿Has verificado que la ruta a la que estás apuntando es correcta? En Android Studio puedes explorar el dispositivo para verificar las rutas.

Comment: Quizá sea interesante hacer las pruebas [indicadas aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6942735/5587982) para ver lo que está ocurriendo en tu contexto. Fuera de los `if` podrías imprimir también un log de `state`

Comment: OK. pero tendra que ser ya mañana. Te mando todo lo que ocurra en el Redmi y lo comparo en el Mi A1. Muchas gracias

Comment: Al hacer las puebas indicadas state = "mounted", por lo cual este es el log que se ejecuta:  Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted and writable");

Comment: Verifica que estás apuntando a la ruta correcta. Da la impresión de que hay un error en la ruta.

Comment: con estos string   String pathdestino1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                String pathorigen1 = getActivity().getDatabasePath(DBName).toString(); Sale /storage/emulated/0 y /data/user/0/com.valhondo.delgado.tesoresiainjurios/database/tesoreia.db respectivamente

Comment: Como puedo mirar la ruta de la dase de datos tesoreia.db

Comment: Android Studio tiene un apartado donde puedes explorar el dispositivo (las carpetas y archivos del mismo).

Comment: en los dos movil es el mismo la ruta: /data/data/com.valhondo.delgado.tesoreriainjurios/database/tesoreria.df

Comment: Pero si hablamos de SD Card me suena que la ruta debe tener algo de `sd` o de `storage` o de `external` o algo así. Creo que tienes confusión de rutas y que en el código no estás apuntando al lugar correcto. Revisa la ruta de tu SD con esto: `File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Comment: en el directorio /storage/emuled/ el permiso es denegado en los dos. La diferencia es que en el que no funciona hay un directorio /storage/sdcard0/ donde esta archivo raid que voe en el movil y en el que funciona no existe.

Comment: File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); en los dos es /storage/emulated/0

Comment: No se crear ni directorio ni subdirectorio. Con lo de arriba como prdria crarlo. No sale error pero no la crea y creo que ahi esta el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos razones que provocan lo que comentas cuando llamas el metodo [canWrite()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#canWrite())

- El archivo no existe, retornara false.
- No tienes permisos [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external), retornara false

Suponiendo que tienes los permisos asignados a tu aplicacion.

En este caso la estructura de archivos puede variar entre versiones y entre dispositivos, por esta razon deberias obtener el path origen a partir del nombre de la Base de datos y su ruta, de esta forma:

```
//String DBName = "tesoreria.db";
//File pathorigen = getActivity().getDatabasePath(DBName);

//Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
 String DBName = "tesoreria.db";
 String pathDB = getDatabasePath(DBName).toString();
 File pathorigen = new File(pathDB);
```

---

Si deseas copiar una base de datos, puedes revisar esta respuesta:

[¿Como copiar una base de datos Sqlite o archivo desde el almacenamiento interno al externo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79010/como-copiar-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-o-archivo-desde-el-almacenamiento-interno)

Comment: Y porque si me funciona perfectamente en otro movil que tengo Xiaomi Mi A1 o Redmi 7, pero en este Xiaomi Note 9 NO funciona, ademas tambien no me crea los pdf (pero este es otro tema).

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

Despues de darle un monton de vueltas para Android 10 y API 29 para poder acceder a los documentos publicos a si como crear directorios sed debe de poner en el AndroisManifest.xml en la parte de < Aplicacion .... esto

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Esto no es una soluciòn, en realidad estas permitiendo usar mètodos que son marcados como obsoletos, en Android 11, esto ya no funcionarìa.